# Why can i not make a circles with the mouse?

Tags: java, event-handling, mouseevent, actionlistener

I'm resolving an excercise about to create a closest pair of points. The first satge i'm doing is trying to make a points(cricles) with my mouse. But i got no respons with the left button (just one circle in (0,0)), the others buttons 2 and 3 work fine. I'm stuck in why and how to resolve that? Any hint or help is appreciate.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClosestPairOfPoints extends JFrame {
    // Create a canvas
    private Circle canvas = new Circle();

    public ClosestPairOfPoints() {
        // Create a panel
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        // Add canvas and panel
        add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // add(p);

        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            // Handle mouse clicked event
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                    canvas.createCircle();
                else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2)
                    System.out.println("Try again with the left button");
                else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                    System.out.println("Try again with the left button");
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ClosestPairOfPoints();
        frame.setTitle("Closest pair of Ppoints");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Circle extends JPanel { // Inner class
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int radius = 10; // Default circle radius

        // Create a circle
        public void createCircle() {

        }

        // paint the component
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawOval(x, y, radius, radius);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know you're not getting any response from the "left button"?  You have nothing to indicate it?

Comment: Your `createCircle()` method does nothing.

Comment: When i execute the code, i get the circle in (0,0) and when i clicked on B2 or B3 i get the message but nothing from B1. I'm stuck in how the createCircle() should be? I need just a hint..I don't know..quite simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClosestPairOfPoints extends JFrame {
// Create a canvas
private Circle canvas = new Circle();

public ClosestPairOfPoints() {
    // Add canvas and panel
    add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        // Handle mouse clicked event
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                canvas.createCircle(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2){
                System.out.println("Try again with the left button");
            }else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                System.out.println("Try again with the left button");
          }
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new ClosestPairOfPoints();
    frame.setTitle("Closest pair of Ppoints");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static class Circle extends JPanel { // Inner class
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius = 10; // Default circle radius

    // Create a circle
    public void createCircle(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    repaint();
    }

    // paint the component
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawOval(x, y, radius, radius);

    }
}
}
```

It should work now. You needed to call createCircle and pass it the position of the mouseClick, and then call repaint so the paint component can be called again and the circle redrawn in the correct position.

Haha it seems like another person has posted an answer while I was typing this. As mentioned the event object "e" contains information about the mouse click, so using the getX() and getY() methods, you can get the x and y position of the mouse click.

Also, you don't need the JPanel p = new JPanel(); in your code either.. because "canvas" is already a JPanel and the one you added to the JFrame.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's helps..Thanks a lot. Now i understand the whole pbm and how to reflect (i'm a very new beginner!!).

Comment: No problem, it's hard being a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

The left mouse button is responding normally (did a `System.out.println` with the left mouse button), but, as Hovercraft Full of Eels stated, your `createCircle()` method is empty. That's your problem.

In terms of actually drawing the circle, I won't write the entire code for you, but I'll tell you that `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` will come in handy when figuring out where the mouse is when the mouse click occurred.